# Read multipart/mixed response in Java/Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, httpresponse, apache-commons-httpclient

I am getting a `"multipart/mixed"` response to an http request that I need to parse. One part of the response is a pdf file which I need to save to disk. Is there any library that will do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did in groovy. Needed java mail library:

```
//... get reader from response, can use response.success callback in http.request
ByteArrayDataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(new ReaderInputStream(reader), "multipart/mixed");
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart(ds);
BodyPart part = multipart.getBodyPart(1);
file = new File('/../../path/filename.pdf')
file << part.content
```

Comment: Notice that for Android you should use com.sun.mail:android-mail

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried retrieving it from the request?

```
 CommonsMultipartFile file = request.getFile('myFile') //File
 def offerId = params.offerId //Standard Param
 def index = params.idx //Standard Param
```

This corresponds to a form input like below:

```
<input class="invDocUpload" id="invFileUpload" type="file" name="myFile" size="40"/>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. My apologies for not reading the question correctly.  I was coding to the request, not the response.