# Java serversocket(http) reading binary data from a POST

Tags: java, post, stream, inputstream, serversocket

So, I have a webserver which handles a connection request, **stores the whole request into a String** (the problem relies here I believe), before doing any type of handling.

```
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        // Loop here until there is no more to read, but wait until the first message arrives.
        while (in.ready() || httpRequestString.isEmpty()) {
            // Read one integer at the time and cast it to a character.
            httpRequestString += (char) in.read();

        }
```

Then sends it to HttpRequest class to inspect it and if it is a POST, save the binary data onto a file.

Works fine with a text file, not with a binary file which becomes corrupt.

I know you shouldn't read binary files line by line (specially with a scanner) and write it with a printwriter, but I have to inspect the request and look for the starting and ending boundaries where the file contents are, consequently I came up with the fast temporary code, just goes to show what I have.

```
scanner = new Scanner(body);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (line.equals("--" + boundary)) {
        fileName = scanner.nextLine().split("filename=")[1].replaceAll("\"", "");
        fileType = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.nextLine(); //empty line

        PrintWriter fileOutput = new PrintWriter(rootFolder + File.separator + fileName);
        //FileOutputStream fileOutput1= new FileOutputStream(new File(rootFolder + File.separator + fileName));
        String prev = scanner.nextLine();

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String next = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("reading from: " + prev);
            if (!(next.equals("--" + boundary + "--"))){
                fileOutput.println(prev);
                prev = next;
            }
            else {
                fileOutput.print(prev);
                break;
            }
        }
        fileOutput.close();
    }
}
scanner.close();
```

How would one store the whole request at the start, not loose any bytes on the process and be able to inspect the content and extract binary data from it ?

Answer (score 0):

By reading your java source code, you seems to try parsing a mime multipart response. May be you should consider using the java.mail API. Here is a link to a post about this API : [Read multipart/mixed response in Java/Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656436/read-multipart-mixed-response-in-java-groovy)

Comment: I don't think it will solve my problem. My guess is that I'm loosing data while casting int to char: httpRequestString += (char) in.read();